# How to decide maximum RAM for my System?

Tags: windows-7, memory

The configuration of my system(Desktop) is the following:

> Processor: Dual core E2140, 1.60 GHz
>   OS: 64 bit Windows 7
>   Motherboard: Mercury PVM890M

I am looking for 4 GB DDR2 RAM. But, will the dual core processor will utilize the RAM fully or not? Also, I want to know, can I use DDR3 RAM. Currently my PC has 1 GB DDR2 RAM

Answer (score 1):

Your computer won't be able to use DDR3 Ram.

The general rule is the more the better.
4GB is generally enough for most tasks though, light/casual gaming, web browsing, application development.

It's only when you start playing heavy games or virtualisation that RAM really gets chewed up.